# SQLite Database not inserting or validating values on Android, no error in codes

Tags: android

I am very new in android programming (2 months into this), so pardon me if I am doing anything wrong. I have been trying to solve this issue for the past week.

I am doing an app which users are able to register, and afterwards log in. However when I run the set of codes (posted below), both registration and login function does not insert/validate the values with my database.

There is no error in logcat as the code runs smoothly.  just not inserting or retrieving data for validation. Apologies for any wrong formatting!

DbHelper.java

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DB_NAME = "TestDB";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Users";

public static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "FirstName";
public static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "LastName";
public static final String KEY_NRIC = "NRIC";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "Username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
public static final String KEY_DOB = "DateOfBirth";
public static final String KEY_COUNTRY = "Country";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "Address";
public static final String KEY_POSTALCODE = "PostalCode";
public static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "PhoneNumber";

public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE '" + TABLE_NAME + "' ("
        + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " VARCHAR (20), "
        + KEY_LASTNAME + " VARCHAR (20), "
        + KEY_NRIC + " VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_EMAIL + " VARCHAR (100), "
        + KEY_USERNAME + " VARCHAR (20), "
        + KEY_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR (20), "
        + KEY_DOB + " VARCHAR (10), "
        + KEY_COUNTRY + " VARCHAR (100), "
        + KEY_ADDRESS + " VARCHAR (500), "
        + KEY_POSTALCODE + " INTEGER (6), "
        + KEY_PHONENUMBER + " INTEGER, "
        + "PRIMARY KEY ('" + KEY_NRIC + "'))";

public DbHelper (Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    this.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public void registerUser (Users users) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, users.getFirstName());
    values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, users.getLastName());
    values.put(KEY_NRIC, users.getNRIC());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, users.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_USERNAME, users.getUsername());
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, users.getPassword());
    values.put(KEY_DOB, users.getDateOfBirth());
    values.put(KEY_COUNTRY, users.getCountry());
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, users.getAddress());
    values.put(KEY_POSTALCODE, users.getPostalCode());
    values.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER, users.getPhoneNumber());
    values.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER, users.getPhoneNumber());
    values.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER, users.getPhoneNumber());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public String AuthenticateLogin (String Username) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + KEY_USERNAME + ", " + KEY_PASSWORD + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    String user, pass;
    pass = "not found";
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME));
            if (user.equals(Username)) {
                pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD));
                break;
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return pass;
 }
}
```

Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

Button login;
public TextInputEditText username;
public TextInputEditText password;
TextView register;
DbHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    username = (TextInputEditText)findViewById((R.id.txtUser));
    password = (TextInputEditText) findViewById((R.id.txtPass));
    register = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.registerText);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login();
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    password.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                login.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void login() {

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

    String user = username.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();

    String aPass = dbHelper.AuthenticateLogin(user);

    if (pass.equals(aPass)) {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        InputMethodManager hideKeyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        hideKeyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(login.getWindowToken(), 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username or password is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer to your question. But I use RealmDb for my app. Try looking into it. It's a very fast db for mobile platforms with less implementation hassles

Comment: *just not inserting or retrieving data* does this mean that the table is empty?

Comment: @GeorgeArokiam thanks, will look into it!

Comment: @mTak the table has pre-populated data. However, if i try to insert data via the registration function it is not inserting any values into the table

Comment: How were these data inserted?

Comment: Through DB Browser, mainly to check the login function since registration does not work, but it turns out both functions are not working